# xCode substituting part of a URL when using NSURL

Tags: xcode5

I am working on an app that connects to a web site using NSURL......

When the app load it looks up a record from the MySQL server and returns data if a record is found, this works. It passes the data back to the app using json, this works.

The data returned forms a part of the URL I want to use to load the web view.

The code I have so far is:

```
NSString *RoomID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",roomid];

NSURL url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/apps/conf/lhr/location/devices/d1/template.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

What I would like to to is substitute

/location/devices/d1/template.php

/location/devices/... the **RoomID**.../template.php

After reading lots of posts I just can't workout how to do this. Any help would be great.

Regards,

DCJ

Comment: Hi Jay, many thanks for your reply. I am having issues making your code work and thats down to my lack of knowledge with xcode. I want to try and work this out using the code you gave me before I ask for more help. Many many thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSString class has some nice ways of replacing strings in other strings. Here's an example:

```
NSString *firstString = @"http://example.com/apps/conf/lhr/location/devices/d1/template.php";
NSString *roomID = @"d68";
NSString *newString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"d1" withString:roomID];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

The above assumes that you'll always replace "d1" with the new roomID, and that your URL will never contain "d1" anywhere else (otherwise those occurrences would also be replaced).

You could also add the slashes to the string and replace "/d1/" in case "d1" is not unique enough. The outcome is the same:

```
NSString *firstString = @"http://example.com/apps/conf/lhr/location/devices/d1/template.php";
NSString *roomID = @"d68";
roomID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/", roomID];
NSString *newString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/d1/" withString:roomID];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

You can remove parts of a string by replacing the occurrence with @"" (nothing):

```
// removing something from a string
NSString *string = @"abcdefg";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"cde" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
// abfg
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Hi Jay, this working as far as it is inserting "roomid=2", how can I remove "roomid". 2014-08-19 11:32:07.513 Conf1[12233:330b] Network is reachable.
2014-08-19 11:32:07.547 Conf1[12233:60b] PostData: devicename=iPad Simulator
2014-08-19 11:32:07.662 Conf1[12233:60b] Response code: 200
2014-08-19 11:32:07.662 Conf1[12233:60b] Response ==> {"success":1, "roomid":2}
2014-08-19 11:32:07.663 Conf1[12233:60b] {
    roomid = 2;
    success = 1;
}
2014-08-19 11:32:07.663 Conf1[12233:60b] http://www.example.com/apps/conf/lhr/location/devices/roomid=2/template.php